# Transforming plain text into text an xml document can handle?

Tags: xml, text

Is there a method to transform a string of text, into text I can place into an .xml document?  Mainly, I just want to replace characters like `"` or `<` with their `&quot;` or `&lt;` equivalent.

```
___text.txt______
This is some "text" I'd like to put into an .xml document
```

...transformed so I can paste it into a document like this...

```xml
___theme.xml______
<desc>
    This is some &quot;text&quot; I'd like to put into an .xml document
</desc>
```

(Sorry to ask what has to be a very basic question, researching this or even just looking for tools or converters has proven frustratingly fruitless.  Maybe I'm lacking the correct words for what I'm trying to do?)

Comment: When you are using languages/tools/etc. that natively support XML, XPath, XQuery, XSD, XSLT, they are doing automatic encoding of XML entities when needed. There are 5 pre-defined entity references in XML: "less than, "greater than", "ampersand ", "'apostrophe", and "quotation mark". In reality just first three need to be encoded.

Comment: As the answers demonstrate, there are many libraries that do this, and which you choose will depend on your choice of technology platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Powershell script which does not need any tools installed.  XML does not need the quotes escaped.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$Filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$text = 'This is some "text" I''d like to put into an .xml document'

$root = '<desc></desc>'
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($root)

$desc = $xDoc.Root;
$desc.SetValue($text)

$xDoc.Save($Filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example that shows what I mentioned in the comments.

It shows, one of many methods, how to compose a well-formed XML in MS SQL Server.

SQL Server natively support XML data type. As well as XQuery and XSD.

The output shows an ampersand that is automatically encoded as `&amp;`.

**T-SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [contract] VARCHAR(50), Vehicle VARCHAR(50) NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Contract, Vehicle) VALUES 
('Car', 'Truck & Light Truck'), -- ampersand is here !!!
('Car', 'SUV');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT TOP(1) ID, Contract
    , 'Vehicle might contain encoded XML entities' AS [comment()]
    , Vehicle
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY ID
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Contract>Car</Contract>
    <!--Vehicle might contain encoded XML entities-->
    <Vehicle>Truck &amp; Light Truck</Vehicle>
  </row>
</root>
```